# Animation of swing div is being affected by other divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm using trying to implement a swinging effect on hover and its working perfectly but when i add different effects to other elements, its effect is getting affected!

```
<!-- THIS CODE BRAKES SWING-->
<div id="abc"> <a href="#" title="Social Cause" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Litter','','Images/abc2.png',1)"><img src="Images/abc1.jpg" width="203" height="311" id="Litter"></a>
</div>
```

css:

```
  #litter {
    position: absolute;
    left: 483px;
top: 0px;
    width: 203px;
    height: 380px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

js

```
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
    var i, x, a = document.MM_sr;
    for (i = 0; a && i < a.length && (x = a[i]) && x.oSrc; i++) x.src = x.oSrc;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
    var i, j = 0,
        x, a = MM_swapImage.arguments;
    document.MM_sr = new Array;
    for (i = 0; i < (a.length - 2); i += 3)
    if ((x = MM_findObj(a[i])) != null) {
        document.MM_sr[j++] = x;
        if (!x.oSrc) x.oSrc = x.src;
        x.src = a[i + 2];
    }
}
```

heres a fiddle where it is swinging properly! http://jsfiddle.net/9eceztyk/

Comment: Too much code, please make a jsfiddle. PS there is no need to include your Google Analytics scripts. Suggested editing to your question.

Comment: @Tibbers I've added a fiddle,.. can u please help me out now!

Comment: Your fiddle does not seem to match your question.

Comment: @APAD1 the fiddle shows how it should swing! shall I put a fiddle that tells how it swings aftr adding another element?

Comment: The fiddle shows a swinging element using CSS animation, your question implies animation using Javascript. Also, your fiddle does not replicate the issue you are describing.